# Radeon RX 580 through Virtual Box

Tags: linux, virtualbox, gpu

I just purchased a Radeon RX 580 graphics card which I would like to pass through virtual box to use on my linux distro.

Does anyone know how I could accomplish this or get more resources that could help guide me?

Thank you.

Comment: This is highly dependent on your CPU.  It must support VT-d and/or AMD's version of it.

Comment: Have you tried to google this? Show us your research and where you got stuck.

Comment: Have you started with the VBox manual? https://docs.oracle.com/en/virtualization/virtualbox/6.0/admin/pcipassthrough.html